# two build types - duplicate code. Not good solution

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio 3.4

I have the next activity:

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
        someCommonMethod()
    }

    private void someCommonMethod() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Now I have 2 build types: `debug` and `release`.
In `debug` I add method  `someDebugMethod()` to activity

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
        someCommonMethod()
        someDebugMethod()
    }

    private void someCommonMethod() {
        // some code
    }

    private void someDebugMethod() {
        // some debug code
    }
}
```

In `release` I add method  `someReleaseMethod()` to activity

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
        someCommonMethod()
        someReleaseMethod()
    }

    private void someCommonMethod() {
        // some code
    }

    private void someReleaseMethod() {
       // some debug code
    }
}
```

I read official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#sourceset-build)

and now project's stucture is:

```
app\src\debug\java\com\myproject\CartActivity.java
app\src\release\java\com\myproject\CartActivity.java
```

I remove `CartActivity.java` from `app\src\main\java`.
So, as a result, I have two files `CartActivity.java`.

Nice.

And now when I start the app in `debug` build type then run`CartActivity` in **debug** folder.
And when I start the app in `release` build type then run`CartActivity` in **release** folder.

Nice. It's work fine.

But suppose now I need to update the common method `someCommonMethod()`. This method used in **both build types**.

As a result, I need to update **TWICE** this method. First in `app\src\debug\java\com\myproject\CartActivity.java` and
then update same method **with same code** in `app\src\release\java\com\myproject\CartActivity.java`

**So I think this is not good.**

Because this is **duplicate** code. I need to **copy & paste** **EVERY** time in **TWO files** when update method `someCommonMethod()`.

It's really bad.

How to avoid this duplicate code?

The ideal approach is when in `CartActivity.java` has only **delta**.

1. In `app\src\debug\java\com\myproject\CartActivity.java` has **ONLY** method `someDebugMethod()`
2. In `app\src\release\java\com\myproject\CartActivity.java` has **ONLY** method `someReleaseMethod()`

and **common** code is in `app\src\main\java\com\myproject\CartActivity.java`

Is it possible?

P.S. Suppose I have 3 build types.
As result, I need to update same code **in three files**. It's really not good.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a `CommonCartActivity` in

```
app\src\main\java\com\myproject\CommonCartActivity.java
```

Then extend the class overriding the methods in the flavor implementations.

```
public class CartActivity extends CommonCartActivity {

    protected void someCommonMethod() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

In this way `CartActivity` just inherits from `CommonCartActivity` with nothing else, duplicated in two flavors.

Comment: But I in real project I has about 20 different activities (for debug and release). So I need to create 20 CommonXXXActivity classes ?  It's not very good.

Comment: @Alexei For all activities do you need to have different behavior for debug and release?

Comment: Yes, I have different for 20 activites. In app I has total  50 activities

Comment: Check if the differences are large to require 2 different classes, or if you can manage little conditions inside the same class.

Comment: What about this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56270432/two-build-types-one-is-equal-to-main-as-result-empty-activity

Answer (score -1):

I think you do not need to complicate the structure of the project. Just use the real-time check.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

    someCommonMethod();

    if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
        someDebugMethod();
    }else{
        someReleaseMethod();
    }
}

private void someCommonMethod() {
    // some code
}

private void someDebugMethod() {
    // some debug code
}

private void someReleaseMethod() {
    // some release code
}
```

---

But, if you need to separate the code, try using one `activity`, but create a new `class` (for example, `Fork`) in two copies for release and debug. Create an instance of the `class` in the `activity`. In this `class` there will be a `doMetnod()` which will have the necessary code depending on the type of project. So you avoid duplication of the `activity` code.

Comment: Suppose I has 3 build types. What about  real-time check in this situation?

Comment: @Alexei BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE

Comment: If I use BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE then in all my app in many places I has smt like this "if BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE == xxx) then ... else ..."  . As result real-time check is mix with application's logic. Is not very good.

Comment: @Alexei. yes, but complicate structure also not very good. Can you check second part of my answer, I think it will help.

Comment: But I in real project I has about 20 different activities (for debug and release). So I need to create 20 ForkXXX classes ?  It's not very good.